# Dynamically load data into a Django Template from a Django Modal without page refresh

Tags: json, django, django-models, treeview

I have the following Django model and I use the first 3 fields to generate a tree-view in the template as shown below.

```
class operationTemplates(models.Model):
    templateID = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    templateCategory = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    templateName = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True, null=True)
    templatePreopBundle = models.TextField( blank=True, null=True)
    templateIndication = models.TextField( blank=True, null=True)
    templatePosition = models.TextField( blank=True, null=True)
    templateProcedure = models.TextField( blank=True, null=True)
    templateClosure = models.TextField( blank=True, null=True)
    templatePostOpInstructions = models.TextField( blank=True, null=True)

                                <!-- tree view -->
                                <ul class="tree">
                                    <li>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="c0" />
                                        <label class="tree_label" for="c0">Vascular Surgery</label>
                                        <ul>
                                            {% for k, v in group.items %}
                                            <li>
                                              <input type="checkbox"  id="c{{forloop.counter}}" />
                                              <label for="c{{forloop.counter}}" class="tree_label">{{ k }}</label>
                                              <ul>
                                                  {% for x in v %}
                                                    <li><span class="tree_label"><a href="{{ x.templateID }}">{{ x.templateName }}</a></span></li>
                                                  {% endfor %}
                                              </ul>
                                            </li>
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <!-- tree view end-->
```

[Tree-View generated dynamically using date from the above modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxlEb.jpg)

When the user clicks on a particular leaf of the tree, I want to be able to query and display all the fields relevant to that record from the Danjo Model without a page refresh.

What is the best way to achieve this? Do I need to use JSON/JavaScript?
Or is there an elegant way to do it just with Django and HTML?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append your response to your div

```
$("button").click(function() {
    //get the templateID
    var templateID = $(this).val();

    // GET AJAX request
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "{% url 'loadSelectedTemplate' %}",
        data: {"templateID": templateID},
        success: function (response) {

            // display the template loaded from AJAX
            var instance = JSON.parse(response["template"]);
            var fields = instance[0]["fields"];
            console.log(fields);
           ===>$("#opnoteTextArea")opnoteTextArea.append(fields)
           

        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log(response)
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax. In your template write the ajax code. In your view render json from your object. If you need an example let me know, its not very hard to do.

Simple example but you get the point:

Put this in your template:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  success: (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Make a view with request and render json

```
   if request.method == 'GET':
        objects = list(YourModel.objects.all().values())
        return JsonResponse({'context': objects})
```

Dont forget to put the url in your urls.py

Comment: Dear Saro thanks for your answer. Can you please give an example?

Answer (score 0):

I have converted the tree leaves into buttons and used AJAX to dynamically query the Django model.

**template**

I want to populate this text area;

```
<form class="addOperationForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                        <table width="100%">
                           
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <textarea id="opnoteTextArea" name='opnoteTextArea' placeholder='Edit your opnote here!' rows="25"></textarea>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <br>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <input class="ner-btn" type="reset" value="Reset">
                                    <button class="ner-btn" id="addOperationNote" type="submit">AddNote</button>
                                    <button class="ner-btn" id="opnoteNER" type="submit">OpnoteNER</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
```

when you click on these buttons;

```
{% for x in v %}
<button id="tree_label" value="{{ x.templateID }}">{{ x.templateName }}</button>
{% endfor %}
```

I use the following javascript to capture the click event

**Script**

```
$("button").click(function() {
        //get the templateID
        var templateID = $(this).val();

        // GET AJAX request
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "{% url 'loadSelectedTemplate' %}",
            data: {"templateID": templateID},
            success: function (response) {

                // display the template loaded from AJAX
                var instance = JSON.parse(response["template"]);
                var fields = instance[0]["fields"];
                console.log(fields);

            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log(response)
            }
        })
    });
```

**views.py**

```
def loadSelectedTemplate(request):
    # request should be ajax and method should be GET.
    if request.is_ajax and request.method == "GET":
        # get the template matching the ID
        templateID = request.GET.get("templateID", None)
        # check for the template matching ID in the database.
        template = operationTemplates.objects.filter(templateID = templateID)
        if template:
            # if template found return record
            ser_template = serializers.serialize('json', [ template, ])
            return JsonResponse({"template": ser_template}, status = 200)
        else:
            # if nick_name not found, then user can create a new friend.
            return JsonResponse({"template":False}, status = 200)

    return JsonResponse({}, status = 400)
```

But I can't still figure out how to populate the textarea using the JSON response.

Have tried different methods and none seem to work;

```
document.getElementById("opnoteTextArea").value += fields;
```

Comment: Request.is_ajax is deprecated in version 3.1 django. Are you using an older version?